# How to test the current logged in user in test class?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

I need to cover the below method where I am using the current logged in user in the query.

```
@Auraenabled  
public static User getUserInformation()    
{  
    User user1 = new User();  
    user1 = [Select Id, Dom__c from User where id=: userinfo.getUserId()];  
    return user1;   
}
```

Comment: would it not always run because test class will run by a logged in user always? so everytime userinfo would return a row...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit tests have a running user, too, just like any Apex code. If you were to write a unit test that called this method, e.g.

```
@isTest
public static void does_query_current_user() {
    System.assertEquals(UserInfo.getUserId(), myClass.getUserInformation().Id, 'got the right user');
}
```

and then go into your IDE or Developer Console and ask to run the test, *you* would be the running user. `UserInfo.getUserId()` would return your user Id, and the query would find your user record.

In some situations, you'll be testing code that is dependent on *who* the running user is (this code is not). In those situations, your unit test will often need to create and insert its own User record that has the correct role and profile, and then invoke the code that's being tested within a `System.runAs()` block:

```
User myTestUser = UserFactory.createTestUser();
System.runAs(myTestUser) {
    System.assertEquals(UserInfo.getUserId(), myClass.getUserInformation().Id, 'got the right user');
}
```

Then, the running user *inside the `runAs` block* will be `myTestUser`, and that user's Id will be returned for `UserInfo.getUserId()`.